# sentiment analysis by sentence similarity

Tags: natural-language-processing

How can sentence similarity be used for sentiment analysis? I know we have sentence Bert which can use cosine sim to measure the distance between to vectors (the sentence embeddings), but has anyone used to for sentiment analysis specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Using a probabilistic language modelling approach to compute the probability of a sentence brings a performance concern.

If we had the following set of documents:

q1: I like this movie

d1: Such a great film

d2: I hated this movie

Using a probabilistic language model we would be able to infer that q1 is probabilistically closer to d2 than to d1, despite that being true we would be wrongly classifying the documents.

In order to compute sentiment analysis a text classifier is usually needed, using supervised machine learning classification methods such as Naïve Bayes, Logistic Regression, SVM, K-nearest Neighbours.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that measuring the similarity of two sentences probably isn't a useful way to do sentiment analysis.  There are better methods for sentiment analysis, so rather than adopting the artificial constraint that it must work by measuring the similarity of two sentences, it's better to use standard methods (I expect they will perform better).

Comment: "There are better methods": curious to know which.